# How to check if .NET programmability support is installed for Word 2007?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-interop, office-2007

Does anyone know how to check if the Office Interops were installed?

I know it is an advanced option when installing Office 2007. Is there a way to install the support after Office is already installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, totally. You can used a tool called [Component Check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/cc563937%28v=office.12%29#VSTO3SolutionPart1_PreparingyourDevelopmentComputer) to see if the PIAs (Primary Interop Assemblies) are installed. You can create a Component Check and PIA Installer following [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20151222072937/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vsto/archive/2008/05/08/adding-the-office-primary-interop-assemblies-as-a-prerequisite-in-your-clickonce-installer-mary-lee.aspx).